# Как раскодировать результат полученый с другой страници html

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю проект и столкнулся с тем что надо передать данные полученные с одной html страницы на другую. Но когда я это делаю и получаю результат у меня выводит  `?%3Cp%3E%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BC%.....`. Как это исправить?
Вот код программы с одной страницы

```
for (key in outputDate) {

             out.innerHTML += `<p>${key} = ${outputDate[key].toFixed(4)}</p>`;

             win='file.html?'+`<p>${key} = ${outputDate[key].toFixed(4)}</p>`;

            window.open(win,'blank');
```

И с другой, на которой я должен розпечатать ответ с первой

```
        window.onload=function()
        {
            let result=location.search;
            document.getElementById("calculator__output").innerHTML+=result
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо использовать функцию [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('%3Cp%3E%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BC'));
```